# HTMLBody refuses to output the font size I specify, always ends up a different size

Tags: c#, css, outlook, office-interop, font-size

I'm trying to get my C# application to generate form emails. I should have had this wrapped up in an hour on Friday...but Outlook is being quite disobedient.

It seems that no matter the way I specify the font size in the MailItem's HTMLBody, it comes out a *slightly* different size. The Font face always comes out as specified, but the size is never right.

```
email.HTMLBody = "<p style='font-size:11px;font-family:Calibri;'>girl look at that body</p>";
email.HTMLBody = "<style> body { font-family:'Calibri'; font-size:11px; } </style> <body>girl look at that body</body>";
email.HTMLBody = "<html><header><style> body { font-family:'Calibri'; font-size:11px; } </style></header> <body>girl look at that body</body></html>";
email.HTMLBody = "<span style='font-size:11px;font-family:calibri;'>girl look at that body</span>";
```

produces size 8.5 font.

```
email.HTMLBody = "<html><body><font face='Calibri' size='11px'>girl look at that body</font></body></html>";
email.HTMLBody = "<font face='Calibri' size='11px'>girl look at that body</font>";
```

produces size 12 font.

So, it seems to be that specifying 11px (or 11pt, tried that too) font via CSS gets me 8.5px, and by font tags gets me 12px.

I've done a little further toying with this, and basically, the font tag produces 12pt font no matter what. So that's a dead end, but I knew the font tag was deprecated anyway.
The CSS tag will give me different sizes, but rarely what I'm asking for. It's always off, and not by a consistent amount.

font-size in code = font-size in email:

- 12 = 9
- 13 = 10
- 14 = 10.5
- 15 = 11.5
- 16 = 12
- 17 = 13
- 18 = 13.5
- 19 = 14.5
- 20 = 15

Specifying 14.5px in CSS gives me my desired 11px...but I don't feel comfortable deploying something that depends upon that.

What's the issue here? Is there something I'm neglecting to specify in CSS? Something I need to adjust elsewhere in MailItem, or Outlook.Application?

Answer (score 9):

It is because you used 11px instead of pt. "px" stands for pixels, and 1 pixel size of text does not mean 1 point in font size. Use 11pt instead of 11px.

Per this discussion here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/199/point-vs-pixel-what-is-the-difference

> A pixel is a single square 'picture element' (hence pix-el), i.e. a single dot in your image. A 10x10 image is made up of a set of a set of pixels in a grid 10 wide by 10 deep, totalling 100 pixels.
>
> The 'point' (pt) on the other hand is a unit of length, commonly used to measure the height of a font, but technically capable of measuring any length. In applications, 1pt is equal to exactly 1/72th of an inch; in traditional print technically 72pt is 0.996264 inches, although I think you'll be forgiven for rounding it up!
>
> How many pixels = 1pt depends on the resolution of your image. If your image is 72ppi (pixels per inch), then one point will equal exactly one pixel.

Comment: I mentioned in the paragraph right after the code that I also tried using 'pt' in all the places I used 'px', but got the same results.

Comment: I know this is really old, and I wish I would have thought of this back then, but what if what we're discussing is just a matter of size difference with the font itself? Just to see what I mean, go here: [Type Tester](http://www.typetester.org). You can change the base font size on the far right to be 14px, and compare between Calibri, Arial (not a huge difference), and Times New Roman (huge difference). Perhaps Calibri isn't the font you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

This is old but I had the exact same problem as OP and found a solution that worked for me. Format the HTML as seen below:

```
.HTMLBody = "<style> body{font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt;}" & "<HTML><body>Your text goes here"
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that some setting in the email is set to downsize from whatever your specified font is. This may vary by different user settings. You state that it is "not by a consistent amount," but I disagree. Based off your numbers, all even values are coming out at `.75` the amount you state, while all odd values are about `.76xxxx`. So it is like the mail is set to multiply your given font size by roughly the equivalent of `.75em`.

Yes, you could compensate by taking your target value and multiply by roughly `1.33`, but are you only doing that for yourself? In other words, as I originally stated, this may be a user specific setting (which may by default be `.75` in Outlook, I don't know), in which case you cannot guarantee font sizing across all users.

Perhaps sizing the font in `em` units may work here. If you give a `1.33em`, that may get you the most consistency to your target size, and also responds to user settings.

In looking at a version of Outlook myself, I could not identify for sure a setting to specifically scale fonts. Default font sizes could be set, and maybe scaling occurs based on some formula of default size to requested size.

Answer (score 1):

I had about the same problem when writing a VBA macro that made an Outlook email with Excel data. Funny part was that no matter what I did, use pt or px, none of it mattered: which ever value I used, the output always skipped over font size 11. Using 11pt gave me 8.5 font size. Using 12pt gave me 9. Using 14 gave me 12...

Anyway, when I **added a decimal** it suddenly worked. **So try this: 11.0pt**. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Try this: `<span style="font-size:11pt">`

I hope it helps.

Comment: The OP states that both 11px & 11pt had the same result.